# How to read the value of fields in signed PDF using PDF Box API

Tags: pdfbox, docusignapi

Once after completion of digital signature for PDF using DocuSign, How to read value of the fields in PDF using field ID/Name (using PDF Box API)? I am not able get the field ids of Digitally Signed PDF.

Comment: Please provide sample PDFs.

Comment: @mkl please download PDF from [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xqkla3t2d0urv6u/SOMA-YouView_CSR_Signing_Order_Form.pdf?dl=0).

Comment: Ok, I'll look at it.

Answer (score 1):

The sample PDF showed that *the fields in PDF* are not PDF form fields after all, neither Acrofornm nor XFA, they merely are texts with some lines around them. (They may once have been PDF form fields which were flattened, or they may never have been PDF form fields to start with.)

Thus, your only option left is text extraction. PDFBox has a quite elaborate text extraction engine. Have a look at `PDFTextStripper`. You can try and use this class as is, looking in the extracted string for the field labels and extract the following text until the end-of-line; or if you have the time, you can try to make use of the internal PDF structure where the field contents are in a separate Xobject.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't understand your last point i.e "make use of the internal PDF structure where the field contents are in a separate Xobject". Can you elaborate this or give me some example.

Comment: *I didn't understand your last point* - the content of a single page in a PDF is not necessarily located in a single stream. There may be multiple streams concatenated, and furthermore additional streams can be referenced from them. The latter ones are called form xobjects. In your sample document the field contents are contained in such a separate xobject. If that is typical for your DocuSign-signed documents, you can try and make use of that fact. This means use of PDFBox low level APIs, though.